# Evaluating a complex integral in punctured plane.

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to evaluate the complex integral $$\int \frac{z}{z+2} dz$$
And $$|z|=3$$

We can see there is a pole at $z=-2$. 
How do I go about solving this, what is the strategy?

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula would be a natural candidate.

Comment: On what contour are you evaluating the integral?

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforwardly Cauchy formula

$$\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz=2i\pi f(a)$$

So in our case $-4i\pi$.

Another way is to parametrize the circle $z=3e^{i\theta}$ which means $dz=3ie^{i\theta}d\theta$ and the integral is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{9ie^{2i\theta}}{3e^{i\theta}+2}d\theta$$

And you should be able to take from there

Comment: but what about the pole? Dont we have to do something like contour deformation?

Comment: The pole is $-2$ and does not belong to the contour $|z|=3$